# How to call a function within a class method property?

Tags: php, function, class

I am trying to call an external function within a class method property. It actually does gets called but at the end of the page and whatever is inside the method property, remains separate.

Since I am a self taught student, it is recent that I have started learning PHP classes so I am not really sure if this can be done or not.

Please guide me how this can be done correctly or if not, then what could be the workaround?

The class I have written is as follows:
It will take the input from user while creating of instance and render a modal box based on the input and options selected.

```
class modalBox{
        private $modal_id, $modal_anim, $header_title, $modal_content,$footer;
        private $headerOpt,$titleOpt,$footerOpt,$closeBtn;

        public function setID($id){
            $this->modal_id = $id;
        }

        public function getID(){
            $modal_id = $this->modal_id;
            return $modal_id;
        }
        public function setTitle($title){
            $this->header_title = $title;
        }

        public function getTitle(){
            $title = $this->header_title;
            return $title;
        }

        public function setBodyContent($content){
            $this->modal_content = $content;
        }

        public function getBodyContent(){
            $modalContent = $this->modal_content;
            return $modalContent;
        }

        public function setFooterContent($footer){
            $this->footer = $footer;
        }

        public function getFooterContent(){
            $footerContent = $this->footer;
            return $footerContent;
        }

        public function initiateModal($modal_anim, $headerOpt, $titleOpt, $closeX, $footerOpt, $footerCloseBtn){ ?>

            <div class="modal <?php if($modal_anim != 'false'){echo $modal_anim;} ?>" id="<?php echo $this->getID(); ?>" style="z-index: 2;"> 
                <div class='modal-dialog'>
                    <div class='modal-content'>
                        <?php
                            // display if header option is set to true
                            if ($headerOpt){
                        ?>
                            <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4><?php echo $this->getTitle(); ?></h4>
                            <?php
                                // display if close button (X) is set to true
                                if($closeX){
                            ?> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                            <div class="modal-body"><?php echo $this->getBodyContent(); ?></div>
                        <?php if($footerOpt){ ?>
                            <div class="modal-footer"><?php echo $this->getFooterContent(); ?>
                            <?php if($footerCloseBtn){ ?>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

The function I am trying to call within property is as follows;
This function is not inside a class. This is present independently in functions.php which I have included in index file.

```
function getDocNameList() {
        global $db;
        $getDoc = $db->prepare("SELECT id,doc_name from doctor");
        $getDoc->execute();
        while($docName = $getDoc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

// print the returned rows in options list of <select>
            echo "<option value='".$docName['id']."'>".$docName['doc_name']."</option>";
        }
    }
```

The initiation of class instance is as follows, Please note where I am calling the function

```
// create class instance
            $rangeModal = new modalBox;

            //set the modal id
            $rangeModal->setID ("rangeFields");

            //set the modal title in header
            $rangeModal->setTitle("Select Date Range");

            // set the body content
            $rangeModal->setBodyContent("
                <form method='post' action='expenditure.php'>
                    <div role='wrapper' class='input-group mb-3'>
                        <input id='datepicker1' name='exp_date_from' value='From Date' required/>
                    </div>
                    <div role='wrapper' class='input-group mb-3'>
                        <input id='datepicker2' name='exp_date_to' value='To Date' required/>
                    </div>
                    <div role='wrapper' class='input-group mb-3'>
                        <select>" . getDocNameList() . "</select>
                    </div>

            ");

            //set the footer content
            $rangeModal->setFooterContent("
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='submitRange' />
                </form>
            ");

            /*
            *   @args ---
            *   modal animation
            *   modal header (boolean)
            *   modal title (boolean)
            *   modal close X (boolean)
            *   modal footer (boolean)
            *   modal footer close button (boolean)
            */

            // initiate modal
            $rangeModal->initiateModal('fade',true,true,true,true,true);
```

I expect the output of the function to be displayed as .... within the  block but instead it gets rendered at the bottom of the page just before  tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `echo` it here, so it will be displayed immediately:

```
echo "<option value='".$docName['id']."'>".$docName['doc_name']."</option>";
```

So it is not concatenated here, the function does not `return` anything:

```
<select>" . getDocNameList() . "</select>
```

Build it and `return` it instead:

```
$output = '';

while($docName = $getDoc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $output .= "<option value='".$docName['id']."'>".$docName['doc_name']."</option>";
}
return $output;
```

Or build an array and join the elements:

```
while($docName = $getDoc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $output[] = "<option value='".$docName['id']."'>".$docName['doc_name']."</option>";
}
return implode($output);
```

Comment: Good pick up but he needs to put *all* the values into a string and return that... (the echo is in a `while` loop)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Wow. This worked like a charm. Just learnt a new thing :) Thanks a lot :)